# How to hide controller name from url cakephp 2.6.9 for all my functions name?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

For example currently my url is:

```
http://www.totalcableusa.com/frontends/troubleshoot
```

my expected url is:
    http://www.totalcableusa.com/troubleshoot

How can I do this using routing in cakephp?

Bear in mind I need a solution for more than one route. e.g. 'index', 'troubleshoot', 'tariffplan' and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work only for troubleshoot page but not for others pages.
Try this

```
Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'Frontends'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/config/routes.php

write the below line

Router::connect('/troubleshoot',array('controller' => 'frontends', 'action' => 'troubleshoot'));

Comment: This solution for one function but I have many function like 'index', 'troubleshoot', 'tariffplan', 'whytotalcable', 'contactus', 'newses', 'reseller', 'shipping', 'package'.

Comment: So you have to as "Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan" said